# First spatial derivative of a differentiable function is a convection or advection term?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that:

Convection is the movement of a fluid, typically in response to heat.

Advection is the movement of some material dissolved or suspended in the fluid.

On wikipedia it says "Advection is sometimes confused with the more encompassing process of convection which is the combination of advective transport and diffusive transport."

The equation I'm studying is from finance context so I cannot apply this two definitions in my case. This is the equation, the function $u$ is the price of a financial derivative.

$$u_{t}-au_{xx}-bu_x+cu-d\int_{\mathbb{R}}u(t,z)f(z-x)dz=0$$

The equation is from an article where it is said that $u_x$ is a convection term. But in other articles they called it an advection term.

In general, all these reaction, diffusion, advection, convection terms have to deal with different derivatives of the same function ?

Comment: In transport theory a term such as $-b u_x$ is called an advection term.

Comment: Ok thanks, and an advection term is always a first order spatial derivative ?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. In higher dimension, it is usually $- v\cdot \nabla_x f$

Comment: Ok thank you Gribouillis